# Unable to list files in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to hadoop.

I am trying to list all files present in my hdfs with this recursive code.

```
public void list(String path) throws IOException {
    Path dirPath = new Path(path);
    FileStatus[] fileStatus = fileSystem.listStatus(dirPath);
    if(fileStatus != null) {
        for (FileStatus fs : fileStatus) {
            String name = fs.getPath().getName();
            if(fs.isDir()) {
                System.out.println("dir --> " + name);
                list(dirPath.getName() + "/" + name);
            } else {
                System.out.println("file --> " + name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am not getting the files list.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How is your `fileSystem` initialized? Does the configuration you must pass contain the namenode address?

Comment: Configuration conf = new Configuration();    
conf.addResource(new Path("~/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/core-site.xml"));    
conf.addResource(new Path("~/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));    
fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

Comment: Can you verify that `fs.default.name` points to your namenode's address (by `conf.get("fs.default.name")`)?

Comment: Its pointing to hdfs://localhost:9000

Comment: And have you initialized your Filesystem object properly? It should be something like `Configuration conf = new Configuration();` `FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);`. And the `uri` should contain the `hdfs:///` prefix if you are trying to get data from HDFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed, you have to initialized your Filesystem object properly. It should be something like:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
```

And the `uri` should contain the `hdfs:///` prefix if you are trying to get data from HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> rmIterator = fs.listLocatedStatus(new Path(srcPath));
while (rmIterator.hasNext()) {
Path path = rmIterator.next().getPath();
if(fs.isDirectory(path)){
System.out.println("Directory Name: "+path.getName());
}else if(fs.isFile(path)){
System.out.println("File Name: "+path.getName());
}
```

`